# Фильтрация списка фильтров в django-filter

Tags: python, django, django-filter

Здравствуйте, у меня есть фильтруемая модель

```
class Sku(object):
    manufacturer = ForeignKey(SomeModel)
```

Я хочу отфильтровать по полю manufacturer, но с учетом только тех manufacturer которые есть у отображенных Sku, не подскажете куда смотреть?
Немного кода о котором речь:

```
class SkuFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    # manufacturer__title = django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='icontains')

    class Meta:
        model = Sku
        fields = ['manufacturer', ]


# кусок из views 
# ...
     c['skus'] = self.object.skus.filter(hide=False, prices__price_type=PRICE_ROZN).prefetch_related('prices',
                                                                                                        'stock').all().order_by(
            'prices__value')
        sku_filter = SkuFilter(self.request.GET, c['skus'])
# ...
```

То есть в итоге может быть 4 товара в c['skus'], а производители в фильтре отображаются все, а нужны только те что есть у этих четырех товаров.

Answer (score 0):

Я сделал таким образом:
создал нужное мне поле без фильтра, магия метаклассов сделала свое дело и создала base_filter, подменил выборку.

```
class SkuFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    def __init__(self, data=None, queryset=None, prefix=None, strict=None):
        self.base_filters['manufacturer'] = django_filters.filters.ModelMultipleChoiceFilter(
            name='manufacturer',
            to_field_name='title',
            queryset=Manufacturer.objects.filter(
                pk__in=queryset.values_list('manufacturer').distinct()),
        )
        super().__init__(data, queryset, prefix, strict)

    manufacturer = django_filters.filters.ModelMultipleChoiceFilter(
        name='manufacturer',
        to_field_name='title',
        queryset=Manufacturer.objects.all()
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Sku
        fields = ['manufacturer', ]
```